# On Atiyah-Macdonald Exercise 3.26

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am trying to prove the exercise 3.26 on Atiyah-Macdonlad:

> Let $(B_{\alpha},g_{\alpha \beta})$ a direct system of rings and $B$ the direct limit. For each $\alpha$, let $f_{\alpha}:A\rightarrow B_{\alpha}$ be a ring homomorphism such that $g_{\alpha \beta}\circ f_{\alpha}=f_{\beta}$ whenever $\alpha\leq \beta$. Then $f_{\alpha}$ induce $f:A\rightarrow B$. Show that 
>   $$f^{\ast}(\mathrm{Spec}(B))=\bigcap f_{\alpha}^{\ast}(\mathrm{Spec}(B_{\alpha}))$$

---

Following the hint, I figured out 
$$\begin{aligned}\mathfrak{p}\notin f^{\ast}(\mathrm{Spec}(B)) &\Leftrightarrow  \varinjlim(B_{\alpha}\otimes_A k(\mathfrak{p}))=0\end{aligned}$$
and
$$\begin{aligned}\mathfrak{p}\notin \bigcap f_{\alpha}^{\ast}(\mathrm{Spec}(B_{\alpha}))&\Leftrightarrow  B_{\alpha}\otimes_A k(\mathfrak{p})=0 \text{  for some }\alpha\end{aligned}$$

By exercise 2.21 on Atiyah-Macdonald, we have

$$ \varinjlim(B_{\alpha}\otimes_A k(\mathfrak{p}))=0 \Rightarrow B_{\alpha}\otimes_A k(\mathfrak{p})=0 \text{  for some }\alpha$$

But I have no idea how to prove the converse, which is true according to Atiyah-Macdonald.

Since the direct limit is the direct sum modulo something, consider the direct sum of $B_{\alpha}$. The zero rings will be killed. The quotient part is unknown but intuitively should not be the direct sum of the rest non-zero rings. Does the fact that $B_{\alpha}\otimes_A k(\mathfrak{p})$ is a $k$-module matter here?

Any hint and answers are welcomed!

Comment: The submodule you quotient out is generated by those relations via direct system.  In particular, if it vanishes at one position, it will vanish in the direct limit under quotient. You are using implicitly a stronger statement by direct limit commuting through direct sum here. Since $B_a$ are all $A-$modules, you can assume module structure and use module structure to deduce.

Comment: @user45765 Could you elaborate your answer a little bit or even write an answer on it? Thanks!

Comment: I made a typo there. I should have said direct limit commuting through tensor product here. It suffices to treat the limit as $A-$module instead. (This is easier to make picture clearer and multiplication structure is not really important here.) Then you know any direct limit of $M_i$ as $A-$modules is $\frac{\oplus_iM_i}{\sim}$ where $\sim$ identifies the image under transition map $M_i\to M_j$.(The quotient is really a submodule generated by those elements.) Then you show direct limit commuting with tensor product. If it vanishes at one position, it has to be $0$ by module map.

Comment: I would recommend Rotman chapter 5's limit section for reference.

Comment: @user45765 thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is **not** true that $\varinjlim B_{\alpha}=0$ if and only if $B_{\alpha}=0$ for some $\alpha$.

Consider the trivial counterexample: the direct system consists of $k$ and $0$ and 
$$0 \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow 0\rightarrow \cdots$$
$$
k \xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}} k\xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}}k\xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}}\cdots $$
where $k$ is a field (also an $k$-algebra). However, we have $B_{\alpha}=0$ for some $\alpha$ and $\varinjlim B_{\alpha}=k~\sqcup \{0\}$, which is obviously not a zero ring.

In fact, we can prove the converse easily. Following the hint, we already prove that 
$$f^{\ast}(\mathrm{Spec}(B))\supset\bigcap f_{\alpha}^{\ast}(\mathrm{Spec}(B_{\alpha})).$$
Now, we need to show
$$f^{\ast}(\mathrm{Spec}(B))\subset\bigcap f_{\alpha}^{\ast}(\mathrm{Spec}(B_{\alpha})).$$
Take a $\mathfrak{p}\in f^{\ast}(\mathrm{Spec}(B))$, that is, there exists $\mathfrak{q}$ such that $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})=\mathfrak{p}$. Suppose the project morphisms $$\mu_{\alpha}:B_{\alpha}\rightarrow B$$
and we have $f=\mu_{\alpha}\circ f_{\alpha}$ for any $\alpha$. So take the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}_{\alpha}=\mu_{\alpha}^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})$, then 
$$f^{\ast}_{\alpha}(\mathfrak{q}_{\alpha})=f_{\alpha}^{-1}\mu_{\alpha}^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})=(\mu_{\alpha}\circ f_{\alpha})^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})=f^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})=\mathfrak{p}$$
It follows that
$$\mathfrak{p}\in \bigcap f_{\alpha}^{\ast}(\mathrm{Spec}(B_{\alpha})). $$

---

So the equivalence the author claimed, that is,
$$\varinjlim(B_{\alpha}\otimes_A k(\mathfrak{p}))=0 \Leftrightarrow B_{\alpha}\otimes_A k(\mathfrak{p})=0 \text{  for some }\alpha$$

is true, by the above equivalence. But I don't know how to prove the converse direction directly so far.

Comment: I don't understand your proposed counterexample. There is no morphism of rings $0 \to k$, if I'm not mistaken: any such ring homomorphism would have to take $0$ to the additive and multiplicative identity in $k$ simultaneously, a contradiction.

Comment: @AlexWertheim good point! Let me think of it.

Comment: @AlexWertheim I edited my answer. Hope this time I didn't make any stupid mistake again.

Comment: I'm afraid it still looks like there is a mistake to me. First, a comment: you don't need to have all those identity maps in your directed system. The directed system with objects $0$ and $k$ with no morphisms between them is perfectly fine, and will have the same direct limit. The mistake (I believe) is where you say $k \coprod 0$ is not the zero ring. Indeed, you are probably thinking of the coproduct as being the disjoint union, but this is not correct (what would the ring structure be?). In the category of rings, the coproduct is the tensor product over the final object $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hence, $\varinjlim B_{\alpha} = k \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} 0 \cong 0$. However, I am deeply confused about the exercise now. The problem claims that the maps $f_{\alpha} \colon A \to B_{\alpha}$ induce a map $f \colon A \to B$, but I don't know what this is supposed to mean. Indeed, if you have a directed system, and maps *out of* $B_{\alpha}$ for each $\alpha$ with the desired commutativity properties, then this should induce a unique map out of $B$. (See exercise 2.16, e.g.). I'm not sure what the problem means by the induced map, since you have maps *into* your directed system...

Comment: @AlexWertheim Yes, you are right: we only need to define the direct system with $0$ and $k$. I think here the ring structure should be the formal addition and multiplication. It is not zero since the element in $k$ is not equal to $0$, according to the definition of equivalence in direct system. But what you said also makes sense to me. Now I am confused...

Comment: @AlexWertheim Here the map is not the one from the universal property of direct limit. Actually, we can consider $A$ as a direct limit of direct system $(A,\mathrm{id})$, so $f$ here is the induced morphism between two directed limits.

Answer (score 1):

In general, $\varinjlim B_{\alpha}=0$ if and only if $B_{\alpha}=0$ for some $\alpha$.

Below is a proof of the fact that $\boxed{ \text{if $B_\alpha=0$ for some $\alpha$, then $\varinjlim B_{\alpha}=0$}}:$

Recall by Exercise 2.21, the multiplicative identity $1\in \varinjlim B_{\alpha}$ is the image of $1_\alpha\in B_\alpha$ under the canonical ring homomorphism $g_\alpha: B_\alpha \to \varinjlim B_\alpha$.
Since $B_\alpha=0$, we have that $1_\alpha=0_\alpha$.
So, $1=g_\alpha(1_\alpha)=g_\alpha(0_\alpha)=0$.

---

Below is an *unnecessary* calculation showing that everything in $\varinjlim B_\alpha$ equals $0$.

Let $u\in \varinjlim B_\alpha$. Then by Exercise 2.15, there exists $v\in B_\beta$ for some $\beta$ such that $u=g_\beta(v)\in \mathrm{Im}(g_\beta)$.

Since the index set is directed, we *can find an index $\gamma\geq \alpha,\beta$.*
Thus,
\begin{align*}
u &= 1 \cdot u 
\\&= g_\alpha(1_\alpha) \cdot g_\beta(v) 
\\&= g_\alpha(0_\alpha) \cdot g_\beta(v) 
\\&= g_\gamma(g_{\alpha\gamma}(0_\alpha) \cdot g_{\beta\gamma}(v))
\\&= g_\gamma(0_\gamma \cdot g_{\beta\gamma}(v))
\\&= g_\gamma(0_\gamma) 
\\&= 0
\end{align*}
, which implies that $\varinjlim B_\alpha = 0$.